# System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert() won't trigger break point

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I notice that the following line of code won't trigger a break under debug mode in Windows 8.1 app, however, it does break under Window 10 app.

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(false);
```

I can see from the output windows the following log message (as an example):

> at App1.MainPage.OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
>      at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame.Navigate(Type sourcePageType, Object parameter)
>      ...

This log message in the console is helpful, but I really hope it will trigger a break point so that we can spot the error earlier. Is there a settings that I can enable the same behavior on Windows 8.1 app?

---

Edit:

This is the code I used for testing:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(false);
    }
}
```

It triggers the break point if I create a Window 10 app but won't if it is for Window 8.1

---

Edit 2:
In response to the comment below, I check the settings, and the `DEBUG` constant is defined and also JIT is enabled:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Running in the debugger and compiled with DEBUG defined is 2 different things. You need the latter. Edit: You may also need to make sure the JIT debugger is registered (that will give you the nice dialog).

Comment: @leppie, thanks for the reply but I tried both and neither of them is working